# Getx Controller receiving null instead of data on first load - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am reaching out because I am relatively new to Flutter and I am currently facing an issue with the GetX Controller package. When I make a GET API request and navigate to another page, the model I receive has null values the first time. However, upon refreshing the page, the data is fetched and displayed correctly.
To provide more context and facilitate assistance, I am sharing relevant sections of my Controller and View code below. I would appreciate it if someone could take a look and help me identify where I might be going wrong.

**Controller**

```
import 'package:app/modules/community/models/post_details_model.dart' as PostDetailsModel;
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../services/dio/api_service.dart';

class PostDetailsController extends GetxController {
  PostDetailsModel.Data postData = PostDetailsModel.Data();
  final postID = Get.arguments;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchPostDetails(postID);
    super.onInit();
  }

  fetchPostDetails(postID) async {
    try {
      postData = (await APIManager.getPostDetails(postID.toString()))!;
    } catch (error) {
      print('List fetch error => $error');
    }
  }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
import 'package:app/helpers/component/custom_elevated_fill_button.dart';
import 'package:app/modules/community/controllers/post_details_controller.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/alfnr_icons.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/text_style_util.dart';
import 'package:another_carousel_pro/another_carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class PostDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostDetailsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostDetailsView> createState() => _PostDetailsViewSate();
}

class _PostDetailsViewSate extends State<PostDetailsView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PostDetailsController controller = Get.put(PostDetailsController());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorUtil.appColorWhite,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 300.0,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: AnotherCarousel(
                  images: [
                    if (controller.postData.thumbnails != null)
                      for (var image in controller.postData.thumbnails!) NetworkImage(image)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              CustomScrollView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverAppBar(
                    pinned: true,
                    snap: false,
                    floating: false,
                    expandedHeight: 230.h,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      background: AnotherCarousel(
                        images: [
                          if (controller.postData.thumbnails != null)
                            for (var image in controller.postData.thumbnails!) NetworkImage(image)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 1200,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.h),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(controller.postData.categoryTitle!,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.sp,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: const Color(0xff0A496B),
                                    fontFamily: AppFont.sfProDisplayFontFamily)),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text('Location: ${controller.postData.location}'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.h, horizontal: 20.w),
                  child: CustomElevatedFillButton(
                    buttonText: 'View 25 Subscriptions',
                    onTap: () => {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: kToolbarHeight),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xffE85175),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
                            child: Material(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Icon(Alfnr.delete, color: Colors.white, size: 18),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xff16A9FA),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
                            child: Material(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  // Get.toNamed(Routes.EDIT_SERVICES,
                                  //     arguments: {"serviceId": postModel.postID});
                                },
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Icon(Alfnr.edit, color: Colors.white, size: 18),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    Get.delete<PostDetailsController>();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**BINDING**

```
import 'package:app/modules/community/controllers/post_details_controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class PostDetailsBindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => PostDetailsController());
  }
}
```

**API Service**

```
static Future<PostDetailsModel.Data?> getPostDetails(postID) async {
    String token = Get.find<GetStorageService>().token;
    Response<dynamic> response = await DioClient(
      isOverlayLoader: false,
    ).get(
      Endpoints.getCommunityPostDetails(postID),
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer $token",
        },
      ),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return PostDetailsModel.postDetailsResponseModelFromJson(response.data.toString()).data;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**DEBUG ERROR**

```
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /POSTS_DETAILS
[GETX] Instance "PostDetailsController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "PostDetailsController" has been initialized
Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
```

Comment: The issue might be in how you are initializing your controller in the UI code. Change the stateful widget to stateless, then instead of  "class PostDetailsView extends StatefulWidget" you extend "GetView<ControllerClass>" Try this.

Comment: @AliJawad Yes, I have tried that too. but the same issue happening. Could you please suggest another solution?

Comment: Oh, I looked at your code again, i am not so sure that is how you pick arguments in Getx, it usually goes something like "var id = Get.arguments["id"]". Can you check now?

Comment: @AliJawad I get the arguments (PostID) from the previous screen and get the data from API successfully, but the issue is when loading the screen the first time.

Comment: Perhaps you can use initstate of stateful widget and call the api function there, if this also doesn't work. You can give me the source code, I will fix it,

Comment: `APIManager.getPostDetails(postID.toString()))!`. Don't use bang operator and then act surprised when null safety is thrown into the trash.

Comment: I got the solution, I have to changed the ```postData``` type to ```Rx<PostDetailsModel.Data> postData = PostDetailsModel.Data().obs;``` and wrap the **Scaffold** by Observer **Obx** widget.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to `find` and not `put` here

```
PostDetailsController controller = Get.put(PostDetailsController());
```

so as

```
PostDetailsController controller = Get.find(PostDetailsController());
```

Comment: @lvo tried it but no luck.